# what is wrong with ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angular and when I am working with ng-repeat, it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var another_app = angular.module('list_app',[]);
  another_app.controller('list_ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.values=[1,2,3,4];
  });
</script>

<p ng-app='list_app' ng-controller='list_ctrl' ng-repeat="x in values">{{x}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `ng-app` & `ng-controller` to a different dom element

```js
var another_app = angular.module('list_app', []);
another_app.controller('list_ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='list_app' ng-controller='list_ctrl'>
  <p ng-repeat="x in values">{{x}}</p>
</div>
```